# Shrine file uploads - One uploader for all file types OR one uploader per file type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, shrine

I'm starting to use Shrine for managing file uploads in my Rails applications. Let's say we have a model `Post` that can have an attached file of multiple types (image, video, audio, etc.) and these files will be processed on upload. Is it recommended to use one **uploader per file-type** or **one uploader for all file-types together**?

Additionally, what would be the best practice to automatically update an attribute `file_type` of the `Post` record on upload?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's recommended to have an uploader per file type, because you will want to handle attachment logic differently depending on the file type, and even choose different storage service.

For example, for images you might want to either process thumbnails yourself, or generate them on-the-fly using a service like [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com).

On the other hand, videos need to be processed differently using different tools, and since that can take much longer you might want to use services like [Zencoder](https://zencoder.com).

In general you might want to load different Shrine plugins depending on the size of files you're uploading, how long does processing take, where are files stored etc. You can still have a `BaseUploader` which would have some common attachment logic, and then have `ImageUploader`, `VideoUploader`, `AudioUploader` inherit from it.

These uploaders can also then branch into multiple uploaders depending on requirements, for example `PhotoUploader` or `CoverUploader`. But you definitely want to have individual uploaders for different file types.

---

For your second question, you can override the Shrine attachment setter:

```
class Post
  include FileUploader[:file]

  def file=(value)
    super
    self.file_type = (file ? file.mime_type : nil)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer (and for amazing Shrine) @janko-m. I still have two questions: **1.** Can I hook multiple uploaders to the same column "file"? This would avoid additional conditional form fields. If yes, how would I tell which uploader to use for the submitted form? **2.** Could you explain overriding the Shrine attachment setter. Is the `file=(value)` method executed every time a file is uploaded and attached to a record? Thanks

Comment: **1.** In this case you should use the `Shrine::Attacher` directly (rather than going through the model), see [this guide](http://shrinerb.com/rdoc/files/doc/attacher_md.html). **2.** This method is executed every time a new file is assigned. It's just a regular attribute writer, Shrine's further uploading and promoting won't trigger this method again.